# could not find cdt include path

Tags: eclipse-cdt, preprocessor, esp32

I am new to Eclipse CDT 2020/9 and installed the [IDF-ESP32-plugin](https://github.com/espressif/idf-eclipse-plugin).

I can compile "Hello World" from within Eclipse and it runs fine on the target hardware.
However, in Eclipse editor view I got lots of errors about symbols that cannot be resolved. These symbols are defined in .h files which are #included in the source - without a failure mark.

Seems that others have the same [problem still unresolved](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=13648&p=53856&hilit=could%20not%20be%20resolved%20hello%20world#p53856).
I found some description about [Preprocessor Include Paths](https://help.eclipse.org/2020-12/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_sd_entries.htm) which I cannot follow because  the menu entry *Preprocessor Include P*... is missing in my Eclipse installation.

An Example:
The first missing symbol is *esp_chip_info_t*. It is declared in *esp_system.h*. I can follow the regarding *#include* by right-click on the filename and choose *Open Declaration*. That means: Eclipse knows where that file is and it contains the symbol.
I wonder why the editor can not resolve that symbol.

Q1: Shall Eclipse editor find that symbol or have I to do something about it?
If Yes, what could be missing in my installation?

Q2: What may be the reason that I do not see the menu entry *Preprocessor Include Path*? I guess if I could use that entry I would be able to help the editor finding the .h file.

Addition: The subject is even more confusing:
There a two .c-files: main.c and hello_world_main.c. In main.c the #inlude files are all *unresoled*, while in hello_world_main.c they have been found by Eclipse. If I follow an #include in hello_world_main.c (F3) I see e.g. esp_system.h. That file itself has #includes, e.g. esp_err.h. They are not flagged *unresolved* but I cannot follow (F3 does not work).

How can I find out why Eclipse behaves as it does?

Comment: the thing which checks the source code in editor in Eclipse CDT is called "C++ Indexer"

Comment: @Juraj Thank you. I selected _Index_ from the projects drop down menu and selected any  entry, including _Search for Unresolved Includes_ resulting in _(0 matches)_. And still, the editor shows lots of _Type could not be found_. Seems the editor does not know what the build system knows. Where to help the editor?